# Why does Java have to throw a Concurrent Modification Exception?

Tags: java, c++, exception, iterator

I would like to know about Java's iterators. Why are they designed to throw Concurrent Modification Exception? In C++ STL, you can iterate over a container and modify stuff as you go but why can't you do it in Java?

EDIT: Corrected question. Was incorrectly framed.

Comment: Its nothing to do with multi-threading. Modifying the underlying collection invalidates the iteration.

Comment: This exception doesn't necessarily only occur when two threads are involved in modifying an object. [JAVADOC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html)

Comment: And they don't do anything to prevent concurrent modification

Comment: Is not necessarily thrown in a multithreaded code. It happens when you modify a collection while it is being iterated. You can get this exception even in single-threaded applications.

Comment: Where do you get the idea iterators are threaded? Your whole presumption is a big non-factual statement...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example of *why* iterators throw up when you try to modify a list when you're iterating over it.

Let's say your iterator is implemented using an index, as in an `ArrayList`: let's say your iterator is pointing to position 3 in the `List` right now.  Now you add an element at position `1`.  The iterator *doesn't know* what changes you've made, so it's still pointing at position 3, but position 3 now holds the element that used to be at position 2, because everything got shifted down.  So your iterator will now visit one element twice!  That's bad.

So the rule is that when you modify a list while you're iterating over it, you have to do so from the iterator itself, so the iterator knows how to keep its position in sync with the modifications to the list.  If you modify the list without going through the iterator, the iterator throws a `ConcurrentModificationException` instead of silently becoming corrupted, e.g. visiting an element more than once.

Comment: But how does this answer OP's question about _being able to do it in C++ and not in Java_?  I think it makes sense to put a note about it in the answer!

Answer (score 4):

You can modify a collection while you're iterating over it. You just have to do it with [Iterator.remove()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29).

[ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) may be thrown, for example, if another thread has modified the collection during iteration. This is preferable to undefined behavior.

Java iterators are not threaded. Multiple threads may exist, and iterators may behave well among these.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of explaining why they are designed the way they are, I will just let you in on this little secret:

If you remove from the list during iteration, you will get a Concurrent exception.
If you remove using the iterator during iteration you could get a concurrent exception for some other reason.

Something like this

```
for(Iterator<?> iter = list.getIterator(); iter.hasNext(); )
{ 
   MyClass c = iter.getNext();
   if( //i need to remove this instance)
      iter.remove(iter);
}
```

wrapping the call in `synchronized` or marking the variable as `volatile` might help you avoid concurrent modification as those will sync the access on the object, preventing you from accessing it from multiple sources at same time.

OR use a [COW list] (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)

I cannot seem to get the hang of how to link stuff on SO today....